# Grafana : how to pass multiple value from variable to another variable in dashboard setting

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have a influx db measurements with something sample like:

supermarket,type=food,item=fish value=12 
supermarket,type=food,item=cake value=7 
supermarket,type=clean,item=tissue value=1 
supermarket,type=clean,item=detergent value=12 
supermarket,type=drink,item=cola value=5 
.....

I would like to have a dashboard in grafana which show the sales of the item. I have set up two variables in grafana setting like:

$type (in query) -> show tag values from supermarket with key=type 
$item (in query) -> show tag values from supermarket with key=item where type='$type'

For both of the variables i checked the "mulit=value" and "include All option" option.  But i found that the $item selection only works when i only select one item in $type. otherwise the $item selection will be empty. (Don't work i n multiple selection or checked "All") I believe that it should be some problem in my query string. (But this requirement are simple). do you have any suggestions?